# Is it possible to pass the same variable to all render statements in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm designing an ecommerce website using Node, Express and Pug. When a customer adds an item to their basket, I'd like to display a count of the items next to the basket icon which appears on every page. Like how I can say `app.use(some_middleware_func)` and have it apply to all routes, can I define a variable to be passed to all `res.render('template', { data: some_data })` statements? The only way I can see of doing it is to manually include the information in the `data` object for each statement but that doesn't seem very maintainable.

Hopefully somebody has an idea or perhaps there is a much better way to approach this?

Comment: I'm not skilled in Pug at all, but e.g. in React I would solve this from the client side with some sort of component, that would ask for the data you need to single server endpoint. If you need it in single component, then the data need not to be in whole client application.

Comment: Use `app.locals` like what you have in the other question.